# Most of the apps are not working after I did something on registry

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-registry, windows-search

I searched for how to change the name of the user in the directory and it told me to go to the registry and Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList. I went and change the profileimagepath in my account and my search button in the taskbar and file explorer suddenly stopped working. If I click it, it doesn't open and let me type anything. I went to change it back to the old name but it still doesn't work.

Update: My settings doesn't work too. It closes automatically when i open it. My user also lost administrator.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work " ? What is the problem precisely.

Comment: The search button the task bar and file explorer wont open when I click it.

Comment: Can you make a screenshot of Regedit on the location you've made the change?

Comment: I can't open pictures now. When I open it, it says "No mapping between account names and security IDs was done."

Comment: Have you try to reboot the system ? Are you able to create a new account and to login with this account ?

Comment: Before editing the Registry, in addition to creating a Restore Point, which might not be usable if the system is badly damaged, **create a full disk image**, which allows restoring *exactly* as the system was at the time the image was made. Sorry, too late to help now, but do this next time.

Answer (score 0):

The key should be called ProfileImagePath

Make sure the contents are like `C:\Users\Admin`

Replace Admin with your username.

Replace C with the drive you installed Windows on.

The type should be "[REG_EXPAND_SZ](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/registry-value-types)"

[image]

Comment: It's like that already but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @talhayaser https://pureinfotech.com/restore-registry-backup-windows-10/

Answer (score 0):

> registry and Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows
> NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList. I went and change the profileimagepath
> in my account and my search button in the taskbar and file explorer
> suddenly stopped working.

You are better not to change the profile name and that is now the damage you have.

If the suggestion to Reboot the system does not work, then most likely you will need to back up and reinstall Windows.

If you want to have a different Profile name in USERS than you get with a Microsoft Account, then at this time, make a Local Account as you would like, set up and then change to a Microsoft Account after.

I have done this both ways.